# How to implement a web service client with a signed body and timestamp for Weblogic

Tags: web-services, timestamp, weblogic, signature, wss

I'm trying to implement a simple web service client for a webservice with enabled WSS (signed body and timestamp). This is the WSS policy:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="SignatureRequired"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToInitiator">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10 />
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:TripleDesRsa15/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict />
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
            <sp:SignedParts>
                <sp:Body />
            </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

The client implementation is based on an example from the Oracle documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24488/message.htm#WSSOV273
and the web service is running on Weblogic 12c (12.1.2) and Oracle Java 1.7.0_25

```
package com.example.testclient.mtom;

import weblogic.jws.jaxws.ClientPolicyFeature;
import weblogic.jws.jaxws.policy.InputStreamPolicySource;
import weblogic.security.SSL.TrustManager; 
import weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.api.Timestamp;
import weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.api.WSSecurityFactory;
import weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.provider.CredentialProvider; 
import weblogic.xml.crypto.wss.WSSecurityContext; 
import weblogic.wsee.security.bst.ClientBSTCredentialProvider; 

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.MTOMFeature;

import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import com.example.attachment.TestWebServiceAttachment_Service;
import com.example.attachment.TestWebServiceAttachment;

public class TestWebServiceAttachmentClient {

    public TestWebServiceAttachmentClient() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        String username = "User"; 
        String password = "Pass"; 
        String clientCertFile = "src/main/resources/User.jks";
        QName operationName = new QName("http://www.example.com/ws/attachment", "fileUpload");

        MTOMFeature mtomFeature = new MTOMFeature();

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/my-wssp1.1-signature-required.xml");


        ClientPolicyFeature clientPolicyFeature = new ClientPolicyFeature();
        clientPolicyFeature.setEffectivePolicyForOperation(operationName, new InputStreamPolicySource(is));

        TestWebServiceAttachment_Service service = new TestWebServiceAttachment_Service();
        TestWebServiceAttachment port = service.getTestWebServiceAttachmentPort(clientPolicyFeature, mtomFeature);
        //create credential provider and set it to the Stub
        List credProviders = new ArrayList(); 
        //client side BinarySecurityToken credential provider -- x509
        CredentialProvider cp = new ClientBSTCredentialProvider(clientCertFile, password, username, password);
        credProviders.add(cp);

        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar created = Calendar.getInstance();
        created.setTime(date);
        Calendar expired = Calendar.getInstance();
        expired.setTime(date);
        expired.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, created.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 1);
        Timestamp timestamp = WSSecurityFactory.newTimestamp("TS-" + RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(34), created, expired);

        Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
        requestContext.put(WSSConstants.TIMESTAMP_ELEMENT, timestamp);
        requestContext.put(WSSecurityContext.CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_LIST, credProviders);
        requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "http://myserver:7001/ws/TestWebServiceAttachment/1.0");
        requestContext.put(WSSecurityContext.TRUST_MANAGER, new TrustManager() {
            public boolean certificateCallback(X509Certificate[] chain, int validateErr) {
             // need to validate if the server cert can be trusted
             return true;
           }
        });


        DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(new FileDataSource("src/main/resources/file1.pdf"));
        long response = port.fileUpload("file1.pdf", dh);
        System.out.println("response = " + response);
      }
}
```

The problem is the timestamp. I don't know how to properly add the timestamp signature to the WSS context. Does anybody know how to implement such a client? I receive the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: Timestamp validation failed. Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:125)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:181)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:258)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:117)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:91)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:154)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.fileUpload(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right kind of timestamp? Where is `WSSConstants` defined? `WSSecurityFactory.newTimestamp` probably does not return what you want http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/apirefs.1211/e24391/weblogic/xml/crypto/wss/api/WSSecurityFactory.html

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer probably is not useful for you anymore, but it may help others.
Weblogic Timestamp validation assumes that corresponding fields are in UTC timezone. Check if your datetime fields are in **UTC.**
And `Timestamp validation failed` message is shown by server when there is no timestamp field or timestamp fields are incorrect. You can see your **raw SOAP request** by adding these lines to your code:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump", "true");
System.setProperty("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump". "true");
```